# Using a matrix in Jenkinsfile, is it possible to use different 'agent' blocks based on the matrix value?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a declarative pipeline Jenkinsfile that looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Build and Test") {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PLATFORM'
                        values 'Windows', 'macOS'
                    }
                }
            }            

            stages {
                agent {
                    node {
                        label PLATFORM
                    }
                }
                stage("Stage 1") {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo Stage 1"
                    }
                }
                stage("Stage 2") {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo Stage 2"
                    }
                }
                stage("Stage 3") {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo Stage 3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will run, in parallel, the three stages on two runners which match the `axis` labels. In that particular case labels will match my Windows and macOS runners so I get the same stages running on two platforms.

I'd like to use the same structure and add Linux. Unfortunately the `agent` to use for my Linux runners is not a `node` but rather `kubernetes`. The Linux `agent` should thus look something like this:

```
agent {
    kubernetes {
        defaultContainer 'container_defined_in_yaml'
        yamlFile 'k8s-build-pod.yaml'
    }
}
```

Is it possible to "dynamically" build the `agent` block so that it can setup the `node` agent for Windows and macOS and the `kubernetes` agent for Linux, based on the `label` value?

Answer (score 1):

**Create an agentBlock definition**

Updated pipeline:

- defines a function agentBlock to return a block of code for to specify the agent required to run the pipeline based on `params.PLATFORM`

```
def getAgentBlock(String agentLabel) {
  if(agentLabel == "Windows" || agentLabel == "macOS") {
    agent {
      node {
          label agentLabel
      }
    }
  } else if (agentLabel == "Linux") {
    agent {
      kubernetes {
        defaultContainer 'container_defined_in_yaml'
        yamlFile 'k8s-build-pod.yaml'
      }
    }
  } else {
    error "Unsupported platform: ${agentLabel}"
  }
}

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Build and Test") {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PLATFORM'
                        values 'Windows', 'macOS', 'Linux'
                    }
                }
            }            

            stages {
                getAgentBlock(params.PLATFORM)
                stage("Stage 1") {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo Stage 1"
                    }
                }
                stage("Stage 2") {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo Stage 2"
                    }
                }
                stage("Stage 3") {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo Stage 3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I don't think this works though. Stages should be inside the 'matrix' block. Also, Jenkins does not like having multiple 'when/agent', I get `Multiple occurrences of the when section`.

Comment: OK - Based on your comment, proposed a solution that I used for establishing which report to run as a post action, modified it for an agent block - see above

Comment: This unfortunately does not work either. The function provided does not return the `agentBlock`, but even if I do I Jenkins complain with `WorkflowScript: 69: Expected a stage @ line 69, column 9.` It doesn't like the function call for the `agent`.

Comment: @big_gie I have updated based on the comment above and noticed the error I made. The def was supposed to provide the whole agent block, not a value for the agent interface. Hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't work. It just errors expecting a stage at the getAgentBlock call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible via built-in 'when {}' block:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label EXE_AGENT } // should be avail, if you have 'run always' nodes, it can be skipped.
  stages {
    stage('Init/Check') {  // outside matrix
      steps {
        script {
          //...
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Matrix Init') {
      matrix {
        agent { label "${NODE_LABEL}" }
        when { anyOf {
          expression { params.boxLabel == 'all' }
          expression { params.boxLabel == env.NODE_LABEL}
        }}
        axes {
          // executors matrix
          axis {
            name 'NODE_LABEL'
            values 'Node1', 'Node2', 'Node3'
          }
          // other params matrix (can be several)
          axis {
            name 'OS'
            values 'Win', 'Linux', 'OSX'
          }
        } // end axes -> stages
        stages {
          stage("Workspace Init") {
            agent { label "${NODE_LABEL}" }
            steps {
              script {
                // Init custom workspaces to prevent future missmatches:
                wsMap = misc.defineWorkspaces(wsMap)
                //.... your logic here
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I wander why Matrix use extra agents, even if it not running on node it take executor from...